# How to disable Advanced Content Filter?

Tags: 8

If I add a tag like `<script src="http://mysource"></script>` in the source code side in CKEditor, it appears well in the WYSIWYG side. But if I go back to source side and come back to the WYSIWYG side it has been transformed like:

```
<!--{cke_protected}%3Cscript%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fmysource%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E-->
```

So, I tried to disable *Advanced Content Filter* by unchecking "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" and also by using the `hook_ckeditor_plugin_info_alter`, according to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/249400/85453).

I also tried to add `allowedContent = true` by using [ckeditor_config](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_config).

Unfortunately without any result.

How to disable this filtering, at least for `<script>` tag?

I mention that I need the ability to add my `<script>` tag in CKEditor (my script will load an iframe at this area) and style it.